# iphone flash lite 2.0 support?

Tags: iphone, flash, actionscript-3, flashdevelop

1.i dont have iphone, so may i know does iphone come with pre-installed flash lite 2.0 or above? if answer is Not, if a web page that embed flash lite app. can it prompt user of iphone to install flash lite easily ?

2. where can i get list of phones that support flash lite 2.0 and above?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Ben states, the iPhone doesn't support Flash of any variety.

Regarding (2), there is a [list on the Adobe website](http://www.adobe.com/mobile/supported_devices/handsets.html) which may be of use.

Answer (score 2):

No, the iPhone does not support Flash (lite or otherwise). Apple has been very clear that they have no interest in adding this support. Can't help you with (2).

Comment: I don't know if it's 'official' policy, but certainly it's clear in their unofficial communications.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately mobile Flash support is not high on Apple's priority for one reason or another. For a complete list of Flash enabled phones go here: http://www.adobe.com/mobile/supported_devices/operators.html

Answer (score 1):

Apple's legitimate concern I believe is with the Flash plugin sucking down resources.  Anyone who has used Flash on anything other than Windows (Read: MacOS and Linux) can affirm that the plugin is pretty horrific.  It leaks memory and grinds on the CPU on both platforms, and it has for years now.

My understanding (it was reported about 2 months ago) is that in its frustration Adobe tried delivering an in-house built version of the Flash plugin.  Unfortunately, its battery life was pretty awful. This was linked off Hacker News and is clearly anecdotal, but FWIW: [tumblr](http://adobegripes.tumblr.com/post/231806385/adobe-gets-bitchy-over-the-iphone-and-flash-bit).

However, I also believe the new builds of Flash allow you to compile apps for iPhone, which is probably a more reasonable route to go.  As I recall you could embed an iTunes Store URL in your page and direct iPhone users to grab the app.

Comment: well, i still prefer to say apple is monopolying and worry about competitors.

Comment: How are they a monopoly? They do in fact have plenty of viable competitors, especially in that many people won't touch ATT.

And blocking flash isn't really "anti-competitive"; the reality is most iPhone users don't want every obnoxious flash ad loading, etc.

I'm a big supporter of, as I said, people compiling their flash apps to iPhone apps, which the new Flash studio supports.  If your app is worth using/seeing, I'll download it.  But I don't want to be forced to eat up memory and CPU on a mobile device just to see your animated fluff.

Answer (score 1):

No and never forever.
Read this: http://www.apple.com/hotnews/thoughts-on-flash/